Problem when sign in with google in my supabase project
I came across a problem. What i want to do is simple: to give access to user to app using google but it did not work thus far. I followed the supabase doc and i could not manage to get it done. I am sure i entered right credentials to supabase. Also, i added my production site url to supabase so i can test it in prod. I can see consent screen but when clicked to account want to sign in, it redirects to the this page

My code is in client side is
const handleLoginWithGoogle = async () => {
    const supabase = createClient();
    await supabase.auth.signInWithOAuth({
      provider: "google",
      options: {
        redirectTo: location.origin + "/auth/callback?next=/user/brands",
      },
    });
};

on server side, my code is
import { cookies } from "next/headers";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { type CookieOptions, createServerClient } from "@supabase/ssr";
import getUserID from "@/src/lib/getUserID";

export async function GET(request: Request) {
  const { searchParams, origin } = new URL(request.url);
  const code = searchParams.get("code");
  // if "next" is in param, use it as the redirect URL
  const next = searchParams.get("next") ?? "/";

  if (code) {
    const cookieStore = cookies();
    const supabase = createServerClient(
      process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL!,
      process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY!,
      {
        cookies: {
          get(name: string) {
            return cookieStore.get(name)?.value;
          },
          set(name: string, value: string, options: CookieOptions) {
            cookieStore.set({ name, value, ...options });
          },
          remove(name: string, options: CookieOptions) {
            cookieStore.delete({ name, ...options });
          },
        },
      }
    );
    const { error } = await supabase.auth.exchangeCodeForSession(code);
    if (!error) {
      const userID = await getUserID();
      const { data } = await supabase
        .from("users")
        .select("username")
        .eq("id", userID)
        .single();

      if (!data) {
        return NextResponse.redirect(`${origin}/user/user-info`);
      } else {
        return NextResponse.redirect(`${origin}${next}`);
      }
    }
  }

  // return the user to an error page with instructions
  return NextResponse.redirect(`${origin}/auth/auth-code-error`);
}

